# Find the density of Z

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-distributions

I'm doing this problem from Carol Ash's *The Probability Tutoring Book*

Setup -

Let $Z = min(X,Y)$ where X and Y are independent random variables.

$$X \sim Exp(\lambda = 1) \\Y \sim Exp(\lambda = 1)$$

Find $F_Z(z)$

My attempt:

Since X and Y are independent: $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_X(x)f_Y(y) = e^{-x}e^{-y}$

Now trying to find $F_Z(z)$

$$F_Z(z) = P(Z \leq z) = P(min(X,Y) \leq z)$$

In order for $min(X,Y) \leq z$, **at least** one of $X$ or $Y$ has to be $\leq z$

Graphically it looks like [image]

So we just need to integrate over the shaded area.
$$F_Z(z) = P(Z \leq z) = P(min(X,Y) \leq z) \\ = \int_{x = 0}^{x = z}\int_{y = 0}^{y = \infty}{e^{-x}e^{-y}}{dydx}\  +\ \int_{x = z}^{x = \infty}\int_{y = 0}^{y = z}{e^{-x}e^{-y}}{dydx}$$
$$ = \int_{x = 0}^{x = z}{e^{-x}}(1){dx}\ + \  \int_{x = z}^{x = \infty}{e^{-x}}(1-e^{-z}){dx}$$
$$ = 1 - e^{-z} + {e^{-z}}(1 - e^{-z}) = e^{-z}({1 - e^{-z}})$$

However, the answers in the back state that the answer is $F_Z(z) = 1 - e^{2z}$

I can see intuitively how they would get that. Since X and Y are both exponential random variables with $ \lambda = 1$, Z should be a exponential random variable with $\lambda = 2$...

But, I think my work should've lead me to the same conclusion. Why didn't it? Any pointers please???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$P(\min\{X,Y\} \leq z) = 1-P(\min\{X,Y\} > z) = 1-P(X > z)P(Y >z) = 1 - e^{-2z}$$

The penultimate equality uses the property of $\min$.

Comment: That makes sense, and it is the answer. But I want to know why my work didn't arrive at the correct answer, it seems like mathematically/ logically it would...

Comment: By switch them around do you mean swap the limits of the integral? Why would we do this?

In my head, we're integrating from (this is the 2nd term) x = z to x = infinity and from the top curve to the bottom curve y = 0 to y = z... right??

Comment: Your formula is right. You have a typo at the last step. The $e^{-z}$ would cancel each other out.

Comment: This step
$$1 - e^{-z} + {e^{-z}}(1 - e^{-z})$$?

Isn't it $$(1 - e^{-z}) + {e^{-z}}(1 - e^{-z}) = (1 - e^{-z}){e^{-z}}$$?

Comment: Yes, the $e^{-z}$ cancel out and you get the right answer.

Comment: OH! BLESS! THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR THIS! You've made my day